# Best practices for testing a coin-flip algorithm

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, randomness

I am uncertain what the best approach is to analyze a game's coin flip algorithm. A game that I play uses a coin flip algorithm to determine who goes first (on the play) or second (on the draw), but some people think that its "rigged" based on how much money is spent on the game. Someone gathered data from 46 people for a total of 2074 matches.

When performing a binomial test, his data indicates that people going first significantly deviates from 50% (p= 0.03315), with a confidence interval between 45% and 49%. However, this person argued that only using using p-values as a source of evidence can be misleading, so he continued his analyses looking at the proportion of on people on the play/on the draw and then comparing the correlations between money spent and the proportion of on the play/draw.

The researcher concluded that there was no strong evidence that people who go on the play differs from 50%, and that there was no evidence that spending money affects your rate on the play. However, a critic of his experiment argued that his analyses are misleading. More specifically, he argues that the data suggests that who goes on the play differs from 50%, a chi-squared test should have been used instead of correlations, and that his method of using proportions overestimates people who play fewer games and underestimates people who play a lot of games. I see validity in both sides, but I am uncertain who to side with since both have their merit. How should I interpret his results?

I summed up the problem as best as I could, but below is a video describing everything.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6jWa85VBu4&t=1501s

Comment: Chi-squared analysis of a $2\times 2$ table with rows H and T, columns Go 1st and Go 2nd (or Big Bet and Small) might be a good place to start.

Comment: I have no doubt that some online games rig what ought to be fair coins, dice, or shuffles in order to keep the game 'interesting' for players or profitable for providers. For online casinos, some games are unfair to players with occasional strategically programmed small wins to keep players going in spite of substantial losses. Physical casinos are often heavily regulated by local governments to try to ensure fairness, but there seems to be no regulation of online 'random events' to perform as one is led to believe. // I've refused "opportunities" to help with psych rigging of online games.

Comment: Thank you for your response BruceET. I am not the person who ran the experiment, and thus I do not have access to the raw data. That is why I am asking whether the researcher's methods are valid since he did not perform any goodness of fit tests at all, but instead used his own method. Another person on his youtube video did a binomial exact test using the information available. I know that its a lot to ask, but I was hoping that you or someone else could give their feedback on the video and the claims from both sides.

Comment: From the video: "there is no evidence to support that people who spend more money go on the play more often" this is a conclusion about *players' behavior* not the coin. If you assume that they use a single "coin" then you need a chi-squared or binomial test, other thing is if you assume that the system is playing the players and behaves differently depending on the abounts etc, but that is a completely different and more complicated question.

Comment: Hello Tim. In this case, the null hypothesis is that everyone uses the same coin (everyone has 50% chance of going first). The alternate hypothesis is that the coin is "rigged" in favor of people who spend money (go first more than 50%), and "rigged" against people who don't spend money. Would a chi-squared test or binomial exact test be good for testing whether the coin is really fair for everyone? Or is correlation between money spent and the proportion of play/draw for each person a better test to see that the coin is fair.

Comment: @statsnovice The question is ""Is the coin rigged based on how much money is spent on the game?" so the null hypothesis is not "everyone has 50% chance of going first" but "the coin's results are unaffected by how much money is spent on the game".